# Remove duplicates rows but change column data on the remaining duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, having-clause

I am creating a mailing list of people that I will send to the print shop to have printed out. I figured out how to take out all duplicate addresses but I need a way that I can change the name of the person that lives at the duplicate address to the “Last name” household.  The duplicate addresses tell me that I have an address for two people that live there so instead of sending them two pieces of mail I only send them one, addressed to the both of them. Thanks in advance

This is what I have so far

```
    SELECT First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name AS Name, Mail_Address_1, phone
    FROM    Personal
    GROUP BY Mail_Address_1
    HAVING  COUNT(Mail_Address_1) > 1
    order by  Mail_Address_1
```

Comment: no, I need the duplicates taken out and the name on the remaining row that had the dups taken out I need to change the name

Comment: What if the last names differ at the same address?  Could you give us sample input and output?

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/705/tttttttttttttttttttttttaj.jpg/

Comment: If names don't match, just take the top last name, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using the Windowed functions `ROW_NUMBER()` and `COUNT(*) OVER()`

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN Duplicates = 1 THEN First_Name + ForeName ELSE 'The ' + Last_name + ' Household' END [Name]
        Mail_Address_1,
        Phone
FROM    (   SELECT  First_name, 
                    Last_name,
                    Mail_Address_1,
                    Phone,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Mail_Address_1 ORDER BY Last_name) [RowNum],
                    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Mail_Address_1) [Duplicates]
            FROM    Personal
            WHERE   Registered_Voter = 1
        ) p
WHERE   RowNum = 1
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` limits the results to the top entry for each address, and the `COUNT` dictates which logic to apply, i.e. to a person or to a household.

Comment: would i be able to add to the where clause, for example WHERE RowNum = 1 and registered_voter = 1? thanks

Comment: Yes, but how you would do it would depend on how the rule should work. i.e. if there were 2 people at one address, John and Jane Smith, but only John as a registered voter should it go to the Smith Household because there are 2 people there, or should it just go to John Smith because he is the only registered voter?

Comment: Yes, if there are two matching addresses and only one registered voter between the two, the name would not change and the address with the non registered voter would not show up. So it should check for registered voters first

Comment: You'd need to add it to the subquery to ensure the results for the `ROW_NUMBER` function were not affected. I've added this to the query to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want take out duplicated rows and modify the remaining row to identify it you could use t

```
WITH DUPE (MAIL_ADDRESS_1)
AS
(
    SELECT MAIL_ADDRESS_1
        FROM    PERSONAL
        GROUP BY MAIL_ADDRESS_1
        HAVING  COUNT(MAIL_ADDRESS_1) > 1
)
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME , MAIL_ADDRESS_1, PHONE FROM PERSONAL WHERE MAIL_ADDRESS_1 NOT IN(
    SELECT MAIL_ADDRESS_1 FROM DUPE)
UNION
SELECT TOP 1 FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME + '(DUPE MAIL)' AS LAST_NAME, MAIL_ADDRESS_1, PHONE 
FROM PERSONAL WHERE MAIL_ADDRESS_1 IN (SELECT MAIL_ADDRESS_1 FROM DUPE)
```

or a simple select:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME , MAIL_ADDRESS_1, PHONE FROM PERSONAL WHERE MAIL_ADDRESS_1 NOT IN(
    SELECT MAIL_ADDRESS_1
        FROM    PERSONAL
        GROUP BY MAIL_ADDRESS_1
        HAVING  COUNT(MAIL_ADDRESS_1) > 1
    )
UNION
SELECT TOP 1 FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME + '(DUPE MAIL)' AS LAST_NAME, MAIL_ADDRESS_1, PHONE 
FROM PERSONAL WHERE MAIL_ADDRESS_1 IN (
    SELECT MAIL_ADDRESS_1
        FROM    PERSONAL
        GROUP BY MAIL_ADDRESS_1
        HAVING  COUNT(MAIL_ADDRESS_1) > 1
    )
ORDER BY  MAIL_ADDRESS_1
```

Comment: This wouldn't work quite right. The `TOP 1` limits the second part of the `UNION` to only 1 result in total, not only one result per Mail Address.